# get value of input text with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, input

Hello I've been working on this problem since last friday and I don't understand why val() is returning the id of my input instead of the value.
Here is the markup responsible for the search box:

```
 <div class="multiGameSearch">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm" value="Find Games" id="searchBox"/>
    <button type="button" id="searchGames">Search</button>
 </div>
```

Here is the javascript that is handling it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchGames').click(function() {                   
           var $val = $('#searchBox').val();      
           console.log("Searching for: " + $val);                                 
    });
});
```

For some reason $val is outputting 'searchBox'(which is the input element's id).  Everytime I click the button it changes the value inside the input field into 'searchBox'.  I don't understand what is happening.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jxov66sf/ So  problem is some where else

Comment: Your code works fine for me, and returns "Find Games" or whatever is the value. What browser are you trying this on?

Comment: yes your code is working f9, what are you expecting your code to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/g9dnxx19/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchGames').click(function() {                   
           var $val = $('#searchBox').val();      
           console.log("Searching for: " + $val);                                 
    });
});
```

Comment: No value addition to question

Comment: That's what 4 person did it in comments

Comment: there can be no better answer until OP updates Question. Comments appeared to me after I had given the answer.

Comment: That's what I thought.  My code is right but I guess something else in the code base is changing this.  Thanks anyways.